# Unity DI - Dynamic generated proxy classes are returning me object reference error

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a classic dependancy injection done through constructors. I have logic written to load all the dependancies and initialize container objects at start up of my WebAPI.
But. randomly I keep on receiving this error
"Exception Found:
Type: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Unity_ILEmit_InterfaceProxies
Stacktrace:    at **DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IVisitService_df97406393ea40d0af1606c695169e41.GetPartialVisitsByVisitIdListAsync(List`1 visitInternalIdList)**&#13;&#10;   at Test.Service.Common.Dataset.Util.Service.UtilService.&lt;GetPartialVisitsByVisitInternalId&gt;d__22.MoveNext()&#13;&#10;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#13;&#10;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#13;&#10;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#13;&#10;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)&#13;&#10;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
"

This is purely random and the workaround that I have is if I recycle the app pool, this issue automatically gets resolved.

I believe somehow, the dynamically generated proxy classes are getting turned to not returning instance while making the call to GetPartialVisitsByVisitIdListAsync method.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. It was due to the unnecessary interceptors loaded in the unity config file. Removing them fixed the issue.

```
<register type="Test.Service.Api.Workqueue.IWorkqueueService, Test.Service.Api.Workqueue" mapTo="Test.Service.Workqueue.WorkqueueService, Test.Service.Workqueue">
    <lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
    <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
    <interceptionBehavior type="Test.Core.PerformanceWriter.PerformanceWriterBehavior,Test.Core"/>
  </register>
```

Changed to

```
<register type="Test.Service.Api.Workqueue.IWorkqueueService, Test.Service.Api.Workqueue" mapTo="Test.Service.Workqueue.WorkqueueService, Test.Service.Workqueue">
    <lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
  </register>
```